# Standard system of parameters and an example

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a local Noetherian ring.  A system of parameters $\bf{x}$$:=x_{1}, \dots, x_{d}$ is a standard system of parameters if $(\bf{x})H^{i}_{m}(R/(x_{1}, \dots, x_{j}))=0$ holds for all non-negative integers $i,j$ with $i+j<d$.

I have a couple of questions regarding this concept:

First, do standard s.o.p's only exist in rings of finite length cohomology (ie, generalized Cohen-Macaulay rings)?

Can anyone give an example of a system of parameters in a 2-dimensional ring of positive depth that is *not* standard?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear Lam, do you have any reference or motivation? 

Comment: Actually, I think I've found an answer in the article "Some remarks on generalized Cohen-Macaulay rings" by  M. Fiorentini and L. T. Hoa.  In this article, they say being generalized CM is equivalent to the existence of a standard sop.  So, I guess any sop in a non-generalized CM ring is not standard.